# Converting SPI/I2S to SAI peripheral setup help

Tags: stm32, i2s

Just a quick question, I just need some help figuring out what is what.

The device that I am working with is the: [STM32H753ZI reference](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099-stm32h742-stm32h743753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

I am coming from the I2S peripheral and wanting to setup the SAI peripheral with the I2S configuration

I am curious if anyone can tell me what is what

The SAI has

- Audio Data Size
- Frame length
- and Slot numbers

For the I2S equivalents I believe

- Audio Data Size = DATALEN
- Frame Length = CHANNEL LENGTH

But what the heck is slots?

Comment: Which specific STM32 chip model is this and have you tried reading the reference manual for understanding the SAI peripheral?

Comment: @Justme I have, read it a couple of times. Its just not clicking right now. Ill edit the post but its the STM32H753ZI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slots are audio channels. For example, I2S only has two channels or slots per frame, but other audio interfaces such as AC97 needs 13 slots  so there are more than two channels or slots per frame.

Frame length is how many clocks there are to send all the slots. For example I2S can have a frame length of 64 bits to allow for up to 32 bits per slot.

Audio data size is how many bits of actual audio data there is per slot, as a 32-bit slot can be used to carry only 20 or 24 bits of audio.

Comment: Ahh this was very insightful thank you. Just to recap on my end here. Slots which is new to me is the number of channels, for I2S 2 is max, SPDIF is > 10 I guess. Frame length well at least for the stm32 is max out at 32bit channel length. Audio data size is yeah the actual useful audio data that comes in.

Comment: No, SPDIF is 2 channels too.

Comment: Really? Oh damn how does it do surround sound then? "These standards support simple stereo streams up to high sample rate,
and compressed multi-channel surround sound, such as those defined by Dolby or DTS." Interesting

Comment: @Leoc Dolby and DTS are compressed bitstreams, not linear PCM. The two channels are used to transport the bitstream over SPDIF interface.

Comment: I see I see, interesting. Might have to ask a question about using Dolby and DTS then.