# What is SAI frame synchro?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, audio, digital-communications, digital-audio

The SAI interface, [as used by ST](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/group0/d3/c0/b0/0e/fe/eb/40/a9/STM32H7-Peripheral-Serial-Audio-Interface_SAI/files/STM32H7-Peripheral-Serial-Audio-Interface_SAI.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.STM32H7-Peripheral-Serial-Audio-Interface_SAI.pdf) and [others](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12202.pdf), includes some options which I have not been able to find any explanation of.  [Justme's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/573268/66365) provides a great explanation of frame, slot, and data size; I'd like to know more about frame synchro, how to select size values, and the master clock divider.

My goal is to record audio from a single PDM microphone.

1. What is **Frame Synchro**? For PDM [ST Recommends (p.43-p.44)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5027-interfacing-pdm-digital-microphones-using-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) setting it to half the width of the frame.  Why? What does it do? IDoes it waste half the frame with synchronization bits? And what is "Frame Synchro Definition = Channel Identification"? (I can find no definition of that.)
2. That same doc recommends a Frame Length of 64 bits, a Data Size of 16 bits, and four Slots, each of 16 bits.  **Why those values** as opposed to, e.g. a Frame of 32 bits with two slots of 16 bits? And why must there bean even number of slots - if I have only one mic, why can't I just use one slot?
3. What is the **Master Clock Divider**? The ST doc seems to state that it could be enabled or disabled, without explaining what it does or what difference that makes.

**Update:** I'm referring to [STM32H735](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0468-stm32h723733-stm32h725735-and-stm32h730-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), STM32H735IG, which I'm testing using the included MEMS microphone on the STM32H735G-DK Disco.

Comment: To which specific MCU this relates? Please provide a specific part number, a bare minimum is e.g. STM32F or STM32H series, the three numbers after it, and the two letters which identify the flash and package size.

Comment: @Justme Updated with requested info.

Comment: @Justme What other information can I provide?

Comment: @SRobertJames Have you tried looking at example 4.3 in AN5027? It seems more relevant to using a single PDM microphone. I'm more familiar with the other things you're asking about in the context of I²S (though frame synchronization is important in a lot of protocols, including PDM with multple mics). The SAI module has features to support many different protocols, so not everything is relevant in all situations.

Comment: @camerondm9 Yes, I've found some examples - but am really trying to understand _what's going on and why those params are used_, not just copy and paste the examples.